# What app does Chromecast use to play a video file from HTTP? Does it filter intranet URLs?

Tags: google-cast

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial) a GoogleCast sender app must specify a Chromecast application name to receive commands. Does the Chromecast include a default media player in its installation? I saw a "Fling" app name in a code sample yesterday, but I can't find it again.

If so, and it's able to play a codec-compatible video file through HTTP just by sending it a URL, does it have restrict them in any way to Internet URLs?

Because I'm thinking that using intranet URLs, and forgetting about transcoding, it should be able to consume video files from a NAS or a DLNA server, shouldn't it?

(I'm going to try the moment I can put my hands in one device, of course! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Android Support Library, you can just use the simple form of MediaRouter with the Google Cast libraries to get a default Receiver to play content.  Otherwise, you can create your own receiver, by getting your device [whitelisted](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting). I'll try to add some sample code to this soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it accept URLs from your home network? (I don't see why it wouldn't, but just to be sure. ..)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer? sendControlRequest fails on the chromecast route.